# Closed form of $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{a} \ln^n x}{1+x^{b}} d x$ for natural number $n$?

Tags: integration, trigonometry, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, gamma-function

I am going to evaluate the integral
$$\displaystyle I=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{a} \ln x}{1+x^{b}} d x, \tag*{} $$
where $b>a+1>0$, by its partner integral
$$\displaystyle J(a)=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{a}}{1+x^{b}} d x =\frac{\pi}{b} \csc \frac{(a+1) \pi}{b}\tag*{} $$
using my [post](https://www.quora.com/Is-there-an-elementary-proof-for-displaystyle-int_-0-infty-frac-x-r-x-m-1-d-x-frac-pi-m-csc-frac-r-1-pi-m-where-m-r-1-0/answer/Lai-Johnny).
Differentiating $ J(a)$ w.r.t. $ a$ yields
$\displaystyle \begin{aligned}I &=\frac{\partial}{\partial a} J(a) \\&=\frac{\partial}{\partial a}\left(\frac{\pi}{b} \csc \frac{(a+1) \pi}{b}\right) \\&=-\frac{\pi^{2}}{b^{2}} \csc \frac{(a+1) \pi}{b} \cot \frac{(a+1) \pi}{b}\end{aligned}\tag*{} $

Now I want to find the closed form of the integral in general

$$I_n=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{a} \ln^n x}{1+x^{b}} d x, \tag*{} $$
where $b>a+1>0.$

$$\begin{aligned}I_n &=\frac{\partial^n}{\partial^n a} J(a) \\&=\frac{\pi^{n+1}}{b^{n+1}} \frac{d^n}{d x ^n}\csc x\Big|_{x=\frac{(a+1) \pi}{b}} \end{aligned} $$

**Latest Edit**

Noting that when $n$ is **odd** and $b=2(a+1)$,

\begin{aligned}
I_{n} &=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{a} \ln ^{n} x}{1+x^{2(a+1)}}dx \\
&=\left.\frac{\pi^{n+1}}{b^{n+1}} \frac{d^n}{d x ^n}\csc x\right|_{x=\frac{\pi}{2}} \\
&=0
\end{aligned}

we can deduce that

$$
\boxed{\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{a} \ln ^{2 m-1} x}{1+x^{2(a+1)}} d x=0}
$$
for any natural number $m$ and $a>-1$.

***My Question*** is how to find the last nth derivative. Opinions and solutions are warmly welcome.

Answer (score 5):

There are several formulae for the $n^{\text{th}}$ derivative of $\csc (x)$ (have a look [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=D%5BCsc%5Bx%5D%2C%7Bx%2Cn%7D%5D) for example). The simplest is probably
$$\csc ^{(n)}(x)=i^{n+1} \left(\text{Li}_{-n}\left(-e^{i x}\right)-\text{Li}_{-n}\left(e^{i x}\right)\right)$$ Using it and trying to simplify as much as I could
$$I_n=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{a} \log^n( x)}{1+x^{b}} \,d x$$

$$\color{blue}{\frac{(2b)^{n+1}}{n!} I_n= }$$
$$\color{blue}{\Bigg[\zeta \left(n+1,\frac{b-(a+1)}{2 b}\right)-\zeta \left(n+1,\frac{2b-(a+1) }{2 b}\right)\Bigg]+}$$
$$\color{blue}{(-1)^n\Bigg[\zeta \left(n+1,\frac{(a+1)}{2 b}\right)-\zeta \left(n+1,\frac{b+(a+1)}{2 b}\right) \Bigg]}$$